# How to make a list that can hold both base classes and derived classes?

Tags: c++

Ok so say i have a class of blades(base class) and a subclass of blades called knifes and swords

```
class blades{
...
}
class knifes:public blades{
...
}
class swords:public blades{
...
}
```

now i want to make a list from #include
that can store information about knifes and swords

```
int main(){
    knifes k1;
    swords swd1;
    list<blades> list;
    k1.input();
    list.push_front(k1);
    swd1.input();
    list.push_front(swd1);
};
```

now i can insert these into the list;however, i have no clue how to access them from the list any help about how to do so would be great if it helps the sub classes do have a output() function

Comment: You need to store them as pointers in the list. You cannot store polymorphic items by value, they must be stored as pointers.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is a list of unique pointers to the base class:

```
list<unique_ptr<base>> your_list;
```

Then, you can populate it both with instances of `base` class *and* `derived` class.

Comment: unique_ptr might be considered more idiomatic in this case.

Comment: Yes, I completely agree. Updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

To complete the answer of Roman, you might like this : https://limbioliong.wordpress.com/2013/01/03/storing-c-objects-in-a-stl-vector-part-3/ . It s about vectors but it s exactly the same for list.

EDIT : Using this, here is the complete example given on the site (note the dynamic_cast to get the derived object):

```
typedef unique_ptr<Base> BasePtr;
std::list<BasePtr> listBasePtr;

listBasePtr.push_front(BasePtr(new Base(0)));
listBasePtr.push_front(BasePtr(new Derived(1, 2)));

std::list<BasePtr>::iterator theIterator;

for (theIterator = listBasePtr.begin(); theIterator != listBasePtr.end(); theIterator++)
{
    BasePtr& base_ptr = (BasePtr&)(*theIterator);

    base_ptr -> func();

    Derived* pDerived = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(base_ptr.get());

    if (pDerived)
    {
        pDerived -> func();
    }
}
```

Comment: If your answer would be content-free without the contents of your link, your answer is not an answer: it is a link.  Answers must stand on their own without the content of any link (as SO has found that off-site links are not sufficiently persistent).

Comment: do you have the legal right to repost that?  Moral rights?  By posting it here, you attach a particular license to the code, and the person you copied it form may not agree with your use.  In general, write your own answer: then, include links if they provide enrichment.

Comment: Well, my answer would be basically the same as Roman's so I did not want to repost it. But I should have add the link as comment not as answer, sorry.